# Maximising a cone

Tags: calculus

A cone with semi-vertical angle 45 degrees is to circumscribe a sphere of radius 12cm.  Is there any maximisation problem here, and what can be said about the height and radius of the cone?

The radius is 12√2 and height is 48cm but I have no idea why.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cone is fixed. See [this](http://www.mathalino.com/sites/default/files/users/Mathalino/differential-calculus/065-sphere-inscribed-in-cone.jpg).

Comment: Does that mean there is no reason to use the derivative?